# An integer is chosen at random from the first 1000 positive integers. Probability that is a multiple of both 6 and 8?

Tags: probability

An integer is chosen at random from the first one thousand positive integers. Find the probability that the integer chosen is:

a. a multiple of 6
b. a multiple of both 6 and 8

I've done a, $1000/6=166$ multiples of 6 between 1 and 1000
$166/1000=0.166$

For b, I presume it would be something like:

$\dfrac{1000}{6}+\dfrac{1000}{8}-x$ where $x=\dfrac{1000}{\text{multiples of 6 and 8}}$

But how do you work out the number of integers that are a multiple of both 6 and 8?

Comment: For b., the probability that the integer is a multiple of both 6 and 8 (ie. a multiple of 24). Given there are floor(1000/24) = 41 such numbers, the probability is directly $\frac{41}{1000}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:  For a number to be a multiple of both $6$ and $8$, it has to be a multiple of $\operatorname {LCM}(6,8)=24$

Comment: There is an "if and only if" in there.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't very many multiples:-

(Using *Mathematica*)

```
Select[Range[1000],
 Function[int, Mod[int, 6] == 0 && Mod[Quotient[int, 6], 8] == 0]]
```

output:

```
{48, 96, 144, 192, 240, 288, 336, 384, 432, 480, 528, 576, 624, 672,
 720, 768, 816, 864, 912, 960}
```

*Note*

`Quotient[m, n]` gives the *integer* quotient of `m` and `n`.

**Edit**

For multiples of 6 and 8 (separately):

```
Select[Range[1000],
 Function[int, Mod[int, 6] == 0 && Mod[int, 8] == 0]]

{24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, 168, 192, 216, 240, 264, 288, 312, 336,
 360, 384, 408, 432, 456, 480, 504, 528, 552, 576, 600, 624, 648, 672,
 696, 720, 744, 768, 792, 816, 840, 864, 888, 912, 936, 960, 984}
```

Comment: Why `Mod[Quotient[int, 6], 8]` and not just `Mod[int, 8]`? You missed $24$, $120$, and several other numbers that are divisible by $6$ and divisible by $8$.

Comment: The multiple has to be a divisible by both 6 *and* 8, not either 6 or 8.

Comment: And which of those conditions does $24$ fail?

Comment: I can't think of any time when $24$ is _not_ a multiple of $6$, likewise for $8$, so I think it _is_ both at the same time. Of course, it's possible OP was looking for something other than what they asked for ...

Comment: Multiples of 6 and 8 at the same time, or separately? Posted answers to both interpretations now.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is "multiple of $6\cdot8$".

Comment: Could well be.  The OP has both answers now, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

A6 — multiples of 6, A8 — multiples of 8. |A6 intersection A8| = |A6| + |A8| - |A6 union A8|, A6 intersection A8 would be A24. If you need numbers that are multiples of both 6 and 8, then you just seek for those that are multiples of 24. If you need both sets numbers that are multiples of 6 and numbers that are multiples of 8, then you calculate the A6 union A8.

Answer (score 0):

for a number which is common multiple of both 6 and 8 first we need to find the LCM(6,8) we get 24 then the other multiples are the multiples of 24 which are less than 1000.

number of multiples of 24 are 41

therefore the peobability is $$\frac{166}{1000}+\frac{125}{1000}-\frac{41}{1000}$$

which is equal to

$$\frac{250}{1000}=\frac14$$